# Undefined identifier in InfluxDB query, invalid binary operator INVALID_OP

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

I am querying InfluxDB by bucket name and with a range and I got this error: `"code":"invalid","message":"error @1:56-1:57: undefined identifier r\\n\\nerror @1:53-1:57: invalid binary operator \\u003cINVALID_OP\\u003e"}'` from the following request:

```
client.query_api().query(query='from(bucket:"bucket_name") |> range(start: -1hr)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the response error is a roundabout way of saying that you should use `1h` instead of `1hr`. Be careful with your time range formats and it will hopefully save you some time